# Communication between iPhone(iOS) and Apple TV (tvOS) simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, tvos, apple-tv

How can we communicate among the tvOS(simulator) and iPhone ?

It means if I need to pass some data to tvOS from an application in iPhone , how can we do that.

Can we use  Bonjour for it?

Comment: there are many different ways to do this, including Bluetooth, iCloud, standard networking (TCP/IP, sockets). You have all the standard communications options you'd have when sending data iPhone to iPhone.

Comment: Yes ! but as in bluetooth in tvOS peripheral api has been removed , Actually frameworks are there but they don't have active api to work on tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) of the local network access frameworks have been removed from the tvOS SDK.

You could use Game Center (easy) or CloudKit (more involved) or an external server on the web (ouch!).